# Fourier inversion of an infinitely divisible multivariate gamma measure represented in polar form.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, fourier-analysis, polar-coordinates

Let $\mathbb{S}^{N-1}$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^N$ under the Euclidean norm $||\cdot||$. Let $\mu$ be an infinitely divisible Borel measure. If there exists a finite measure $\alpha$ on $\mathbb{S}^{N-1}$ with respect to $||\cdot||$ equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and a Borel function $\beta:\mathbb{S}^{N-1}\to\mathbb{R}_+$ such that the the Fourier transform of $\mu$ has the form 
$$\widehat{\mu}(\xi)=\exp\left(\int_{\mathbb{S}^{N-1}}\int_0^\infty \left(e^{ir\langle s,\xi\rangle}-1\right)\frac{e^{-\beta(s)r}}{r}dr\alpha(ds)\right)$$
for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^N$, then $\mu$ is called an $N$-dimensional Gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha,\beta$, and we write $\mu=\Gamma^N(\alpha,\beta)$.

My question is: how can $\mu$ be obtained from $\hat{\mu}$?

Comment: Which Fourier inversion theorems do you know?

Comment: So, I am aware of the Fourier inversion theorem where if $\mathcal{F}[\mu](\xi):=\widehat{\mu}(\xi)$ then we can obtain $\mu$ via $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}[\mu](\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}e^{2\pi i\xi\dot\zeta}\mathcal{F}[\mu]d\xi$. However, I am confused as to what to do about the polar representation.

Comment: I think that if $\alpha(ds)=f(s)ds$ then 
$$\widehat{\mu}=\exp\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}(e^{ix\xi}-1)\frac{e^{-\beta(\frac{x}{|x|})|x|}}{|x|}f\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right)dx\right)$$

 but I don't know what to do next or even if this helps.